# wget: downloading a LIVE txt file

Tags: bash, wget

I have this line at the end of my bash script:

```
wget -q $URL -Y off
```

where `URL` is the path to a **LIVE** txt file that contains the console output for my bash script.

**Clarification** on **LIVE txt file** :

This txt file keeps updating along the process since it stores the console output. My shell script contains some "heavy" programs so the console output is very lengthy and the txt file will need some time to be generated (probably 3~5 seconds delay).

**Problem**: sometimes I get incomplete txt file which only contains small portion of the final txt file. (it is expected to get everything before the `wget` command) And interesting enough, most of the incomplete txt files I downloaded is stuck at line 9999. I don't know whether this is limitation or not, but it appears to be fine if the console output is below 5k lines.

**Question:** Is there a way to make `wget` wait for a specific time?

p.s. I know the there is a timeout option `-T` for `wget` and the default is 900 seconds. But my problem is not related to the slow connection but the delay of generating the file.

Answer (score 0):

If this `wget` statement is running *as part of* the script that is generating the output, you are probably running into some sort of output buffering issue...that is, since the script has not yet exited, output has not yet been flushed.

How are you redirecting output?  One way would be to wrap everything other than the `wget` statement in a subshell and redirect the output of *that*:

```
#!/bin/sh

(
  a bunch
  of commands
) > output 2>&1

wget -q $URL ...
```

This ensures that the other commands have completed *and the containing shell has exited* by the time the `wget` runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! And yes the `wget` is part of the script that is generating the output, the output is the txt file and I save it to the local storage. Is there another way to archive this without wrapping everything else?